# Why does my INSERT fail on SELECT permissions when I have change tracking enabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, change-tracking

I have a user in a SQL Server 2014 database that only has permissions to insert into a table (no select permissions). When change tracking is enabled on the table, the inserts will fail with `The SELECT permission was denied on the object ...`

Why is this the case?

Steps to reproduce:

```
USE [master];
CREATE DATABASE insert_test;
GO
USE insert_test;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.test(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, value NVARCHAR(50));
ALTER DATABASE insert_test SET CHANGE_TRACKING=ON;
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;
GO
CREATE LOGIN test_user WITH PASSWORD='FD3nIk1p(4$LKH!eSY';
CREATE USER test_user FOR LOGIN test_user;
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.test TO test_user;
GO
EXECUTE AS USER='test_user';
INSERT INTO dbo.test(value) VALUES(N'hello');  -- Fails with: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'test', database 'insert_test', schema 'dbo'

/*
-- Cleanup
USE [master];
GO
DROP DATABASE insert_test;
GO
DROP LOGIN test_user;
GO
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change tracking operations are running within the user's context, and in order to track what is being changed it has to read the row using a SELECT before it is changed.

Comment: Stored procedures avoid the need to grant any permissions the table.

Comment: Seems a bit nasty that enabling change tracking changes the behaviour of existing query permissions. (CDC doesn't do this)